# ES6 Callback function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback

I am looking through someone else's code and keep seeing functions written in this style:

```
    getConsents: (_, callback = () => {}) => {
        const data = {};
        callback(data, true);
    }
```

I'm aware some use the underscore as a convention for skipping a parameter when it's not appropriate, though I cannot make sense of why the callback function parameter is written in this manner.

I tried using babel to see if it made anymore sense in es5, though was out of luck:

```
getConsents: (function (_) {
  var callback = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : function () {};
  var data = {};
  callback(data, true);
});
```

If someone could explain this convention, or detail what it this is doing, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's a default callback to use if the function invoked without passing one. See [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ES6 you can specify default values for function parameters. For example:

```js
function greet(name = 'John Doe') {
  console.log('hello', name);
}

greet('Alan Alda');
greet();
```

The function in your example is defaulting the callback parameter to an empty function. That way it can blindly call it without checking for undefined first.

Answer (score 0):

In ES5 it might look something like:

```
getConsents: (function(_, callback = function() {}) {
    const data = {};
    callback(data, true);
})
```

It's just setting a default value for the callback.